# Swing events not firing anymore

Tags: java, swing, events

I am dealing with a desktop Java / swing appl. (using Netbeans as IDE).
I created a simple panel which can be opened clicking a button in a general panel.
The panel is correctly opened by clicking that button , but the other objects on this open panel seem not to be able to fire events anymore.
I got back to this program after some week without anyone having modiied it and all of a sudden I find this problem that I didn't have the last time I dealt with it : in efect all the objects on the panel were doing their works.
Could it depend on an update of the JVM that I could inadvertently made ?

I can see that the action listeners (for instance the one on the jbutton1 ) is correctly registered, on the correct event, but its never called .

............

```
        jButton1.setText(resourceMap.getString("jButton1.text")); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setName("jButton1"); // NOI18N
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

................

   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String S;
        int offSet = 0, offsetWrite = 0, length =0;
        char [] buffer = new char [100];
        char [] bufferLast;
        Network Net;
        try
        {

            
             StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
             File F = new File(SelectedFilePath);
             FileReader FR = new FileReader(F);
             
             // see if you can substitute this code with loading a DOM document directly from file
             // and then , turn the DOM document easily into a string to create the network
             
             
 ...................
```

Comment: Based on personal experience, 99% of these are programmers fault, not the JVM's. You'll need to post [self contained runnable code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your issue to have any hope for an answer.

Comment: @predi Wise suggestion, and a tip: `[mre]` in a comment auto-expands to [mre].

Comment: OP: a tip. Noting that the (uncompilable) code (snippet) ends before the `catch`, make sure your MRE includes [`Throwable.printStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) to help track down the error.